# CanvasAuthorizer Authorize() not returning true on facebook C# sdk

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, sdk, authorize

I downloaded the Facebook C# SDK 4.1.1, and incorporated it on a small ASP.NET 3.5SP1 web project.  When I run the application from VS Studio 2008, it allowed me to install my Facebook application.  When I log onto facebook, I can see that my app installed, as I see it on my home page left nav.

When I click on the app, it displays the default.aspx page on my facebook app iframe.  Looks like it worked, right?  No it doesn't because when I debug the page on localhost, I see that the Authorize() on the CanvasAuthorizer app returns FALSE.

I created a web app in IIS 5.0 so that the default vs studio debugger doesn't interfere.

Here are they facebook settings I have set and other relevant information.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Canvas Page
"http://apps.facebook.com/mynewapp/"

Canvas URL
http://localhost/MyNewApp/

Canvas FBML/iframe
iframe

My Page Load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fbApp = new FacebookApp();
        authorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer(fbApp);
        authorizer.Perms = requiredAppPermissions;

            if (authorizer.Authorize())
        {
            ShowFacebookContent();
        }
    }
```

Here are the relevant sections of my web.config:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue:

http://adamyoung.net/IE-Blocking-iFrame-Cookies

The issue was only happening in IE.  IE blocks iframe cookies...have to set the header to allow cookies.