# unable to 'authorize' user with Facebook API after they have 'approved' application?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

When a facebook user tries to visit my facebook app, they get prompted with the standard "Approve this app?". The user approves my app. Then, when my code does the following, the answer is always false:

```
FacebookApp fbApp = new FacebookApp();
CanvasAuthorizer authorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer(fbApp);
authorizer.Perms = "user_about_me";
if (authorizer.Authorize())
{
    JsonObject result = (JsonObject)fbApp.Api("/me");

    return Convert.ToInt64((String)result["id"]);
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Unauthorized Facebook API access.");
}
```

which results in the authorizer.Authorize() always being false and the "Unauthorized Facebook API Access" exception gets thrown.

the user has "approved" my app. so why is this failing, returning false??

i don't even know where to begin to try to debug this problem.

any suggestions?

Comment: i have found another question that is very similar to my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618767/canvasauthorizer-authorize-not-returning-true-on-facebook-c-sdk  and will post back on here once i determine whether or not this suggestion is of any help (http://adamyoung.net/IE-Blocking-iFrame-Cookies)

Comment: -- this only resolved the cookies issue which only resolved 1 testing machine out of 3 machines/computers. the other 2 computers (friends I have testing the app) still have this problem. the problem is now fixed on my computer when I run IE.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your `web.config` file with you App ID and App Secret.
If not put you AppId and Secret like this :

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="facebookSettings" type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection" />
  </configSections>
  <facebookSettings appId="{app id}" 
                 appSecret="{app secret}" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: yes my web.config is set up that way. also, when i personally visit the facebook app with my own facebook account, i do not have this problem: i've already previously "approved" the app with my facebook account, and am also set up as the "developer/administrator" of the facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

It is a cookie problem with IE8. Check to see if you get the error in compatibility mode. If not then add this to all the pages

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
```